Finding the optimised equation for a vector line that intersects two other lines
I have two lines, "mosquitoes", in a 3D space with equations $r_A=(-2,2,3)+t(6,-4,5)$ and $r_B=(3,5,1)+t(-7,-3,4)$. Now I want to find the equation of a line, a "spray",with direction vector $(-3,-2,-3.5)$, or rather velocity $\sqrt{25.25}$ units per second, that intersects both lines. The difficulty is is that for my problem, these lines are not really vector lines, but moving objects, and I need to make sure that after the spray hits the first mosquito, by the time it hits the second mosquito the mosquito is actually there. Basically, I want the spray to "kill two birds with one stone". This is what I've done so far:
I know that this exact question has been asked before and I know that the first solution provided works, however I am not very sure if this is the optimum solution (the least amount of distance).
For the second solution, I didn't really understand where the quadratic form came from. I get that the distance is described by $d=(3,5,1)+t_2(-7,-3,4)-(-2,2,3)-t_1(6,-4,5)=(5-7t_2-6t_1,3-3t_2+4t_1,-2+4t_2-5t_1)$, where $t_1$ is the when mosquito A is hit and $t_2$ is when mosquito B is hit. I then found $|d|^2=(5-7t_2-6t_1)^2+(3-3t_2+4t_1)^2+(-2+4t_2-5t_1)^2$ and substituted in $t_2=t_1+\frac{|d|}{v}$ (as $\frac{|d|}{t_2-t_1}=v$), where $v=\sqrt{25.25}$.
I get an implicit equation,
$$171t_1^2-120t_1+\frac{168}{\sqrt{25.25}}|d|t_1+\frac{74}{25.25}|d|^2-\frac{104}{\sqrt{25.25}}|d|+38=0,$$
so I used partial differentiation to optimise the values, giving me $t_1=\frac{4}{311}$, $t_2=\frac{218}{311}$ and $|d|=3.45767...$, however the time values are equal to the values I get for the shortest distance between the two lines when they are described by different parameters (where the two dot products equal $0$), and the distance value isn't even correct (it should be ~$1.203$). Obviously since I used two parameters, this seems more obvious, but I'm still confused on why this wouldn't work.
Also, even if I form a vector line with the two points of intersection, the velocity I used originally is nowhere to be found, and when I tried using random numbers for the velocity, the time values didn't change. Basically, what I'm asking is, what am I missing? There must be a way to do this but I just can't figure it out. I've thought maybe if I just decide one of the intersection points, maybe I could just use trial and error to find the most optimum? But I don't really know and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hi! Interesting question, but please rewrite the title so that it accurately reflects the content. Thanks!

Oh! You had a sensible title before, and you recently edited it to something irrelevant that would almost surely eventually draw down-votes and close-votes. Please don't do that! :-) I changed your title back to the original.
